# how to use ngnix to serve webpack build files in production

Tags: node.js, nginx, webpack, vuejs2

I wrote a vue + webpack project and it works fine in webpack-dev-middleware. Now I want to deploy it with nginx. What I do is write a webpack.build.config.js and bundle all files into a dist folder. Then I just copy the dist folder into nginx html folder and assign the index in nginx.conf. However, it has an error said:

> [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not
>   defined.  (found in root instance)

I am a newbie for devops/backend and quite confused with the overall build or deploy process. Is webpack-dev-server or nodejs still need in the production environment? My production environment backend is nginx/PHP and IIS/.Net, now it do not have node installed at all.

My nginx.conf is

```
location / {
    root   html/dist;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

And the webpack.build.config.js is

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var public_dir = "components";
//var ModernizrWebpackPlugin = require('modernizr-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        path.join(__dirname,'./index.js')
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist/'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('common.js'),
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'),
            inject: true
        })
    ],
    resolve: {
        root: [path.resolve('./components')],
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.css']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
        ]
    }
};
```

When build I run

> webpack -p --config ./webpack.build.config.js

Comment: For the same case i use ngnix as proxy while pm2 (http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) manages nodejs server process.

Comment: @ArkadyB Kindly elaborate further on how you use pm2. For instance what command do you use to deploy to production?

Comment: @NIMRODMAINA, as stated on PM2 web site, its production process manager for nodejs apps, therefore you build an app with whatever tool you want - webpack or so and use pm2 to run your app in background. Please refer to official website for more info - http://pm2.keymetrics.io/

Comment: @ArkadyB I sorry but I'm new to this. So please forgive me for the armature question. Will the command be pm2 start webpack.build.config.js  or will I point it to the build.js file?

Comment: @NIMRODMAINA, what i was doing is simply running "pm2 start app.js", where app.js is your node js application. They seem to improve a lot since then and now support more features for automatic deployment. Please check their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using  [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) to init vuejs webpack project. And the project already has build script, you can refer it:

```
require('./check-versions')()

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production'

var ora = require('ora')
var rm = require('rimraf')
var path = require('path')
var chalk = require('chalk')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var config = require('../config')
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.prod.conf')

var spinner = ora('building for production...')
spinner.start()

rm(path.join(config.build.assetsRoot, config.build.assetsSubDirectory), err => {
  if (err) throw err
  webpack(webpackConfig, function (err, stats) {
    spinner.stop()
    if (err) throw err
    process.stdout.write(stats.toString({
      colors: true,
      modules: false,
      children: false,
      chunks: false,
      chunkModules: false
    }) + '\n\n')

    console.log(chalk.cyan('  Build complete.\n'))
    console.log(chalk.yellow(
      '  Tip: built files are meant to be served over an HTTP server.\n' +
      '  Opening index.html over file:// won\'t work.\n'
    ))
  })
})
```

After built, we will have a `dist` folder. Upload all files inside to `html` folder of Nginx (default)
Config root path to use full path like this:

```
listen      80;
server_name mydomain www.mydomain;
root /var/www/html;
```